# BASH regex check not matching on linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have been scripting something in BASH and I have found a strange bug. I have been developing on Mac (El Capitan) and everything is working flawlessly. But deployment on Ubuntu 16.06 server is failing and I have no idea why.

My code follows

```
while ! [[ ${someVariable} =~ ^[a-zA-z0-9_-]{40}$ ]]
do
    read someVariable
    if ! [[ ${someVariable} =~ ^[a-zA-z0-9_-]{40}$ ]];then  
        echo 'try again'
    fi
done
```

for input 6LfMYB8TAAAAACRZ9bP-0GN9y4zKUYPtj255-e8A this fails. And failure happens on server only and not on the development machine. I have a feeling that I have missed something obvious.

Comment: What @James says. But also, possible different versions of bash (`bash --version`)?

Comment: A deleted answer mentions the suspicious-looking range `A-z`. Please confirm that your script continues to fail if you replace that with `A-Z`.

Comment: The range was bad, it was a simple typo. Lucky for me was that i copied the whole if. If I had typed it again here I would have not make the same mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your ranges. The upper case range must be from A-Z
This code works on Ubuntu 14.04

```
while ! [[ ${someVariable} =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{40}$ ]]
do
    read someVariable
    if ! [[ ${someVariable} =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{40}$ ]];then  
        echo 'try again'
    fi
done
```

Comment: This. The reason why OP is seeing differing results for `A-z` is due to the locale. It would accidentally work for `LC_COLLATE=C` (the default) and `POSIX`, but would fail for systems using e.g. `en_US.utf8`.

Comment: yes! the problem was caused by simple typo... I feel silly sometimes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this regex?

```
^[-_a-zA-Z0-9]{40}$
```

Comment: Although my problem was due to simple typo I have failed to see (range was A-z instead A-Z) I would like to know why would this regex be better and, of course, why would you suggest this solution. Is this more efficient or...?

Comment: oh i just typed out what I thought would work into a terminal. I figured you would do the diff and figure out what went wrong.